# Как реализовать вывод постов на страницу после добавления без перезагрузки страницы Ajax + php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, база-данных

Через Ajax на сервер передаю данные из формы добавления поста:

```
<script>
    $('#send_post').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:      "controllers/Profile/post.php", 
            type:     "POST",
            dataType: "html", 
            data: $("#send_post_textarea").serialize(),
            success: function (postsJson) {
                success();
                var posts = $.parseJSON(postsJson);
                console.log(posts);
            }
        }); 
    });

    function success() {
        $('#send_post_textarea').val('');
    }
</script>
```

На сервере соответственно данные обрабатываю, в базу записываются успешно:

```
if (isset($_POST['post_text'])) {
        $post_text = $_POST['post_text'];

        $post_text = htmlspecialchars(addslashes($post_text));
        $post_date = date('j/m/Y h:i A');

        $push_post_query = "INSERT INTO user_posts (`user_id`, `post_text`, `post_date`) VALUES ('$user_id', '$post_text', '$post_date')";

        if (!$conn->query($push_post_query)) die('Ошибка при добавлении записи <a href="../../index.php">Попробуйте еще раз.</a>');

        //get users posts
        $get_posts = "SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result = $conn->query($get_posts);
        $posts = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        echo json_encode($posts);
    }
```

После этого на клиенте принимаю json и преобразовываю его в массив:

```
{0: "47", 1: "10", 2: "fsfsf", 3: "14/11/2018 09:20 PM", id: "47", user_id: "10", post_text: "fsfsf", post_date: "14/11/2018 09:20 PM"}
```

Так вот вопрос, как мне сделать чтобы после того как пользователь нажал на кнопку Добавить Пост, посты выводились в ленту без перезагрузки по установленному шаблону с полями для имени пользователя, даты и собственно сам текст. Пробовал через echo возвращать не json, а сам html шаблон, но я не понимаю как мне тогда в нем реализовать подстановку данных о пользователе и прочие данные поста типа:

```
<span><?php= $user['name']; ?></span>
```

и тд, так как получение самих постов с базы находится в другом файле.

А в случае с получением данных в формате json, не понимаю как мне их вывести по типу как `<span><?php= $user['name']; ?></span>`

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_assoc вместо mysqli_fetch_array. Тогда вернется не
`{0: "47", 1: "10", 2: "fsfsf", 3: "14/11/2018 09:20 PM", id: "47", user_id: "10", post_text: "fsfsf", post_date: "14/11/2018 09:20 PM"}` такой ответ.
 А что то подобное `{id: "47", user_id: "10", post_text: "fsfsf", post_date: "14/11/2018 09:20 PM"}`. А в html тэгах куда нужно записать данные. Прописать класс типа new-post-id для каждого тэга итд. А потом на jquery можно написать что то подобное

```
function (postsJson) {
   success();
   var posts = $.parseJSON(postsJson);
   console.log(posts);
   $.each(posts, function (key, val) {
      var className = '.new-post-' + key
      $(className).text(val);
   })
```

}